Ubuntu using to much RAM then normal
My laptop having Ubuntu uses too more RAM than normal, For the past couple of weeks, I was previously using 16 GB RAM and now I have upgraded it to 24GB but even that is not enough, I mostly have 2 windows of VSCODE open and a CHROME browser with 20-30 tabs and Spotify and DB client like db-beaver but still I don't expect it to exceed 24 GB something is not right
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar

Need Help analyzing what can be the issue
top - 16:38:14 up 2 days,  7:02,  2 users,  load average: 1.49, 2.61, 2.28
Tasks: 411 total,   1 running, 410 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.6 us,  1.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.3 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st 
MiB Mem :  23931.7 total,   2629.6 free,  19545.7 used,   2743.1 buff/cache     
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   1091.8 free,    956.2 used.   4386.0 avail Mem 


Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

correcting it @guiverc

I will give you a hint each Chrome tab  can take up to 2 gig of ram

@DavidDE are you suggesting this can be chrome eating up RAM

This question is similar to: Chrome suddenly using too much memory, what's wrong?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
